# Odds Ratio for Reference Class in Multinomial Logistic Regression

Tags: odds-ratio, multinomial-logit

I have the following problem: I have the following problem. Let's say I want to classify in three classes using multinomial logistic regression. Let's call the classes a,b,c. Now, obviously, I only get coefficients for classes a and b (class c is "whatever remains").
Now I would like to explain the influence of individual features on the probability (calculate the odds ratio). That is rather trivial for the influence on a and b, but I am not certain how to calculate the influence on the reference class, c.

For a feature f, the odds ratio for classes a, b is simply given by
$$
\exp{\left(\beta_a^f\right)}\\
\exp{\left(\beta_b^f\right)}
$$

Can I somehow extend this to the odds ratio for class c?

Thank you :)